# Filter List<Map<String, String>> using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to filter a list `List<Map<String, String>`> by value (if map have searched value, then map add to list) using streams. I'm trying to do this:

```
static Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
static Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
static Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<>();

static {
    map1.put("key", "value");
    map1.put("key2", "value2");

    map2.put("key3", "value3");
    map2.put("key2", "value2");

    map3.put("key3", "value3");
    map3.put("key4", "value4");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

    list.add(map1);
    list.add(map2);
    list.add(map3);

    List<Map<String, String>> result = list.stream()
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .filter(value -> value.getValue().equals("value2"))
            .map(x -> resultMap.put(x.getKey(), x.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

For execution this code i have error: 
java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.util.Map
    lower bounds: java.lang.String

Comment: Does this approach work? If not, do you get an error? Or do you get an unexpected result? Which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the `Map`s of the input `List` that contain the "value2" value to appear in the output `List`, you need:

```
List<Map<String, String>> result = 
    list.stream()
        .filter(map -> map.entrySet().stream().anyMatch (e->e.getValue().equals("value2")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or (as Eritrean commented):

```
List<Map<String, String>> result = 
    list.stream()
        .filter(map -> map.containsValue("value2"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to use map.containsValue? `list.stream()
                .filter(map -> map.containsValue("value2")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: If you want to use a Stream operation instead of the straight-forward `map.containsValue("value2")`, it would still be more natural to use `map.values().stream().anyMatch("value2"::equals)` instead of streaming over the `entrySet()` and having to call `getValue()` for each entry.

Answer (score 0):

Another quick solution is removeIf function. Has the advantage of reusing the same list object.

```
 list.removeIf(map -> !map.containsValue("value2"));
```